# switch from SSH key-based authentication to normal account login

Tags: ssh, authentication

The current login method of the server is SSH key-based authentication, I wish to switch it to normal linux login by key in username and password. i understand this is unnecessary, but i have to switch it over. How to do it?

Comment: Does `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password user@host` work? If so, then I can supply an answer.

Comment: what is this command doing?

Comment: It does an `ssh` to your server but sets the "preferred authentication" to "password", that is: it ignores any public/private keys.

Comment: will this command causes me unable to login after applied? Sorry for question too much, just wanna make sure.

Comment: No. It just does an ssh to your server and only for this particular command you will have to supply a password. No configuration whatsoever is changed or stored anywhere. I presume you usually do `ssh user@host` and get logged in with no questions asked. Right? My suggested command just tells `ssh` to ignore the public/private keys and ask for a password instead.

Comment: i usually login to ubuntu by using winscp or putty; in the putty/winscp, the prerequisite is i have to supply the ppk file

Comment: hey @PerlDuck thanks for the replies. by the way, i found the answer by change PasswordAuthentication to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

though it is not recommended, but i need to do it.

Comment: Yes, that was my second guess. The first one was to simply remove your public key(s) from the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server (or rename/delete the file altogether) ***after*** making sure the password login works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside of /etc/ssh/sshd_config

change lines

```
PasswordAuthentication
PubkeyAuthentication
```

!check other options / lines so you don't lock yourself out. If you want to be sure, post your config file here and ask back beforehand.

If the machine is connected to the internet and the ssh port is accessible, you should take this as a warning that you don't fully understand ssh configuration.